# Change values of csv when a specific condition is true in python

Tags: python, pandas, file, csv

I want want to multiply values by 10 which have prefix "0.0".

Below in the example of my csv file.

```
1987-01-14, 0.63, 0.0657, 0.0652, 0.0677
1987-01-15, 0.0639, 0.0662, 0.0652, 0.0676
1987-01-16, 0.0642, 0.0662, 0.0653, 0.0678
1987-01-19, 0.0644, 0.0663, 0.0653, 0.0677
1987-01-20, 0.065, 0.0664, 0.0653, 0.0676
1987-01-21, 0.0652, 0.0666, 0.0658, 0.0679
1987-01-22, 0.0651, 0.0672, 0.0662, 0.0684
1987-01-23, 0.0652, 0.0672, 0.0661, 0.0687
1987-01-26, 0.0654, 0.0674, 0.0663, 0.0688
1987-01-27, 0.0661, 0.0681, 0.0656, 0.0681

import csv
import math,pandas
s = open('input1.csv')
checkIt = csv.reader(s)
for c in checkIt:
       #print(line)
    #values = c.split(',')
    for value in c:
        if "0.0" in value:
            int_v =10* float(value)
            print (int_v)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please try it first yourself. starts with https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: i have added my code please check it, i want to write this data in new csv in same order.

Comment: you csv is not consitant. it has two space some and 4 somewhere. If you have edited here, please don't. paste content as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv
with open('input1.csv') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    lines = list(spamreader)
    for row in lines:
        for i, value in enumerate(row):
            if value.startswith("0.0"):
                row[i] = "{0:.2f}".format(float(value)*10)
with open('eggs.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for row in lines:
        spamwriter.writerow(row)

out:
1987-01-13,0,0.66,0.66,0.65,0.68,0.68
1987-01-14,0.63,0.66,0.66,0.65,0.68,0.68
1987-01-15,0.64,0.66,0.66,0.65,0.68,0.68
1987-01-16,0.64,0.66,0.66,0.65,0.68,0.68
1987-01-19,0.64,0.66,0.66,0.66,0.68,0.68
1987-01-20,0.65,0.67,0.67,0.66,0.69,0.69
1987-01-21,0.65,0.67,0.67,0.66,0.69,0.69
1987-01-22,0.65,0.67,0.67,0.66,0.68,0.68
1987-01-23,0.65,0.67,0.67,0.66,0.68,0.68
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x*10 if "0.0" in str(x) else x)
```

Input:

```
a           b       c       d       e       f       g
1987-01-13  0       0.0657  0.0657  0.0652  0.0678  0.0678
1987-01-14  0.63    0.0662  0.0662  0.0653  0.0677  0.0677
1987-01-15  0.0639  0.0662  0.0662  0.0653  0.0676  0.0676
1987-01-16  0.0642  0.0663  0.0663  0.0653  0.0679  0.0679
1987-01-19  0.0644  0.0664  0.0664  0.0658  0.0684  0.0684
1987-01-20  0.065   0.0666  0.0666  0.0662  0.0687  0.0687
1987-01-21  0.0652  0.0672  0.0672  0.0661  0.0688  0.0688
1987-01-22  0.0651  0.0672  0.0672  0.0663  0.0681  0.0681
1987-01-23  0.0652  0.0674  0.0674  0.0656  0.0681  0.0681
```

Output:

```
            a      b      c      d      e      f      g
0  1987-01-13  0.000  0.657  0.657  0.652  0.678  0.678
1  1987-01-14  0.630  0.662  0.662  0.653  0.677  0.677
2  1987-01-15  0.639  0.662  0.662  0.653  0.676  0.676
3  1987-01-16  0.642  0.663  0.663  0.653  0.679  0.679
4  1987-01-19  0.644  0.664  0.664  0.658  0.684  0.684
5  1987-01-20  0.650  0.666  0.666  0.662  0.687  0.687
6  1987-01-21  0.652  0.672  0.672  0.661  0.688  0.688
7  1987-01-22  0.651  0.672  0.672  0.663  0.681  0.681
8  1987-01-23  0.652  0.674  0.674  0.656  0.681  0.681
```

Answer (score 0):

The best is to use pandas and then do manipulation within that.

Your data doesnt seem to have separators .. or maybe they are just spaces

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('YourFile.csv',sep=' ',header=None)
```

alternatively, if you have saved the csv or data in xls format

```
df=pd.read_excel('YourFile.xlsx',header=None)
df.set_index(0,inplace=True)
```

The last command is needed because the first column is a time stamp index and mathematical manipulations will not work like on the float/number types on the rest of the data, so best to make it an index

```
def mm(x):
  if (x < 0.1):
    y=x*10
else: 
  y=x
return y

df.applymap(mm).to_csv('name of file to save')
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution without converting to `float`s - check if `0.0` and remove first `0` after `0.`. Very important is set `dtype=str` parameter in read_csv for convert all columns to `str`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

temp=u"""1987-01-13 0 0.0657 0.0657 0.0652 0.0678 0.0678
1987-01-14 0.63 0.0662 0.0662 0.0653 0.0677 0.0677
1987-01-15 0.0639 0.0662 0.0662 0.0653 0.0676 0.0676
1987-01-16 0.0642 0.0663 0.0663 0.0653 0.0679 0.0679
1987-01-19 0.0644 0.0664 0.0664 0.0658 0.0684 0.0684
1987-01-20 0.065 0.0666 0.0666 0.0662 0.0687 0.0687
1987-01-21 0.0652 0.0672 0.0672 0.0661 0.0688 0.0688
1987-01-22 0.0651 0.0672 0.0672 0.0663 0.0681 0.0681
1987-01-23 0.0652 0.0674 0.0674 0.0656 0.0681 0.0681"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), sep="\s+", header=None, dtype=str, index_col=[0])

print (df)
                 1       2       3       4       5       6
0                                                         
1987-01-13       0  0.0657  0.0657  0.0652  0.0678  0.0678
1987-01-14    0.63  0.0662  0.0662  0.0653  0.0677  0.0677
1987-01-15  0.0639  0.0662  0.0662  0.0653  0.0676  0.0676
1987-01-16  0.0642  0.0663  0.0663  0.0653  0.0679  0.0679
1987-01-19  0.0644  0.0664  0.0664  0.0658  0.0684  0.0684
1987-01-20   0.065  0.0666  0.0666  0.0662  0.0687  0.0687
1987-01-21  0.0652  0.0672  0.0672  0.0661  0.0688  0.0688
1987-01-22  0.0651  0.0672  0.0672  0.0663  0.0681  0.0681
1987-01-23  0.0652  0.0674  0.0674  0.0656  0.0681  0.0681
```

---

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x:  x.replace('0.0', '0.') if  '0.0' in x else x)
print (df)
                1      2      3      4      5      6
0                                                   
1987-01-13      0  0.657  0.657  0.652  0.678  0.678
1987-01-14   0.63  0.662  0.662  0.653  0.677  0.677
1987-01-15  0.639  0.662  0.662  0.653  0.676  0.676
1987-01-16  0.642  0.663  0.663  0.653  0.679  0.679
1987-01-19  0.644  0.664  0.664  0.658  0.684  0.684
1987-01-20   0.65  0.666  0.666  0.662  0.687  0.687
1987-01-21  0.652  0.672  0.672  0.661  0.688  0.688
1987-01-22  0.651  0.672  0.672  0.663  0.681  0.681
1987-01-23  0.652  0.674  0.674  0.656  0.681  0.681

df.to_csv(file, header=False)
```

---

Solution with `float`s - multiple by `10` if some value is less as `0.1`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

temp=u"""1987-01-13 0 0.0657 0.0657 0.0652 0.0678 0.0678
1987-01-14 0.63 0.0662 0.0662 0.0653 0.0677 0.0677
1987-01-15 0.0639 0.0662 0.0662 0.0653 0.0676 0.0676
1987-01-16 0.0642 0.0663 0.0663 0.0653 0.0679 0.0679
1987-01-19 0.0644 0.0664 0.0664 0.0658 0.0684 0.0684
1987-01-20 0.065 0.0666 0.0666 0.0662 0.0687 0.0687
1987-01-21 0.0652 0.0672 0.0672 0.0661 0.0688 0.0688
1987-01-22 0.0651 0.0672 0.0672 0.0663 0.0681 0.0681
1987-01-23 0.0652 0.0674 0.0674 0.0656 0.0681 0.0681"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), sep="\s+", header=None, index_col=[0])
```

---

```
print (df)
                 1       2       3       4       5       6
0                                                         
1987-01-13  0.0000  0.0657  0.0657  0.0652  0.0678  0.0678
1987-01-14  0.6300  0.0662  0.0662  0.0653  0.0677  0.0677
1987-01-15  0.0639  0.0662  0.0662  0.0653  0.0676  0.0676
1987-01-16  0.0642  0.0663  0.0663  0.0653  0.0679  0.0679
1987-01-19  0.0644  0.0664  0.0664  0.0658  0.0684  0.0684
1987-01-20  0.0650  0.0666  0.0666  0.0662  0.0687  0.0687
1987-01-21  0.0652  0.0672  0.0672  0.0661  0.0688  0.0688
1987-01-22  0.0651  0.0672  0.0672  0.0663  0.0681  0.0681
1987-01-23  0.0652  0.0674  0.0674  0.0656  0.0681  0.0681


df = df.mask(df < 0.1, df * 10)
print (df)
                1      2      3      4      5      6
0                                                   
1987-01-13  0.000  0.657  0.657  0.652  0.678  0.678
1987-01-14  0.630  0.662  0.662  0.653  0.677  0.677
1987-01-15  0.639  0.662  0.662  0.653  0.676  0.676
1987-01-16  0.642  0.663  0.663  0.653  0.679  0.679
1987-01-19  0.644  0.664  0.664  0.658  0.684  0.684
1987-01-20  0.650  0.666  0.666  0.662  0.687  0.687
1987-01-21  0.652  0.672  0.672  0.661  0.688  0.688
1987-01-22  0.651  0.672  0.672  0.663  0.681  0.681
1987-01-23  0.652  0.674  0.674  0.656  0.681  0.681

df.to_csv(file, header=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('input1.csv', sep=',', header=None)
df.applymap(lambda x: x*10 if "0.0" in str(x) else x).to_csv('out1.csv')
```